# How can I get values of the same group several times in Matcher regex Java?

Tags: java, regex

After multiple searches, I come to you.

I made a regex in java :
`^([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]{0,10})( \(([0-9]),([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]{0,10})\))+$`

When I try this : **"S1 (4,S5)"**

It returns :

Group 1 -> **"S1"**

Group 2 -> **" (4,S5)"**

Group 3 -> **"(4,S5)"**

it works well.

But when I try this : **"S1 (4,S5) (2,S3)"**

it returns :

Group 1 -> **"S1"**

Group 2 -> **" (2,S3)"**

Group 3 -> **"(2,S3)"**

It doesn't want to return the **(4,S5)**

How can I get the same group several times ?

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make use of the `\G` anchor to get contiguous matches with 2 capture groups instead of multiple capture groups.

```
(?:^([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]{0,10})|\G(?!^))\h*(\([0-9]+,[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]{0,10}\))
```

The pattern matches:

- `(?:` [Non capture group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html) (for the [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html))

  - `^` Start of string
  - `(` Capture **group 1**

    - `[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]{0,10}` Match a single char a-zA-Z followed by 0-10 times
  - `)` Close group 1
  - `|` Or
  - `\G(?!^)` Assert the position at the end of the previous match, or at the start of the string. As we specify that we have a specific match at the start of the string in the first part of the alternation, we can rule out that position using a negative lookahead using `(?!^)`
- `)` Close non capture group
- `\h*` Match optional horizontal whitespace characters
- `(` Capture **group 2**

  - `\(` Match `(`
  - `[0-9]+,` Match 1+ digits and a comma
  - `[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]{0,10}` Match a single char a-zA-Z followed by 0-10 times
  - `\)`
- `)` Close group 2

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/p0Pt1b/1) | [Java demo](https://ideone.com/isZ80O)

```
String regex = "(?:^([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]{0,10})|\\G(?!^))\\h*(\\([0-9]+,[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]{0,10}\\))";
String string = "S1 (4,S5)\n"
+ "S2 (4,S5) (2,S3)";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

while (matcher.find()) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
        if (matcher.group(i) != null) {
            System.out.println("Group " + i + ": " + matcher.group(i));
        }
    }
}
```

Output

```
Group 1: S1
Group 2: (4,S5)
Group 1: S2
Group 2: (4,S5)
Group 2: (2,S3)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, it works well ! But what is  "?:" and "|\G(?!^))\h*" ?

Comment: @SeeZix I have added an explanation of the pattern.